# How to save linux command line outputs to a .txt file?

Tags: linux, terminal, sh

I would like to make a .sh executable that inputs a terminal command, and saves the output to a .txt file.

For example, take the output of `i2cdump` and save to a file. The terminal commands for this are

```sh
i2cdump -r -y 0x0-6 0 0x68
"outputs the specified bytes 0x0-6 to terminal window"
```

How can I use a .sh executable to do this automatically, and save the output to a file stored in `/dir/`?

Some pseudo code I have for `myfile.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

output=$(i2cdump -r -y 0x0-6 0 0x68)
FILE * fp;
// write output to file
// save to directory
close(fp)
```

Comment: Found this great overview here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file

Answer (score 2):

You can using shell redirection like so:

```sh
echo "Hello world" > greetings.txt
```

Or to suit your needs:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

i2cdump -r -y 0x0-6 0 0x68 > output.txt
# closing is automatic at the end of redirecting.
```

General information about shell redirection of standart output stream in [Bash manual: Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Any command can have > appended to it to redirect the output.
As in:

```
echo "foo" > /path/to/file
```

Note, there are two things you should know:
1 ">" is overwriting a file while >> is appending.
As in:

```
echo "foo" > /path/to/file
```

file content will be:

> foo

while

```
echo "foo" > /path/to/file
echo "foo2" >> /path/to/file
```

file content will be:

> foo
>
> foo2

And also, if you want to redirect errors you can use the 2 operand.
As in:

```sh
cat /path/to/non-existing-file 2> /outputfile
```

Will write all the operation's error into `outputfile`.
The same `>` and `>>` logic applies.